# How to copy contents of one numpy array to another while maintaining indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I want to copy the contents of one array *over* another array, meaning the indices of the copying array are maintained and overwrite the first. In my case, the array being copied into will always be of length `3`, while the copied array will be any arbitrary length.

If the copying array is *smaller* than three, I can do that easily like this:

```
>>>a = numpy.zeros(3, int)
>>>a
a = array([0,0,0])
>>>b = numpy.array([2,3])
>>>a[:len(b)] = b
>>>a
a = array([2,3,0])
```

And if the copying array is *larger* than three, I can do that too like this:

```
>>>c = numpy.array([5,6,7,8])
>>>a = c[:3]
>>>a
a = array([5,6,7])
```

But is there a more elegant numpy method that can do this without havign to write an `if` to catch both of these conditions? Something like `put()` that will allow to copy *up to* a certain index?

**Edit:**

Came up with a one liner that works with an array `x` of any arbitrary size:

```
a[:numpy.min([3, len(x)])] = x[:numpy.min([3, len(x)])
```

But still would like something cleaner

Comment: `a[:len(x)] = x[:len(a)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use-case:

```
a[:len(b)] = b[:3]
```

The trick is to remember that slicing "past the end" of a numpy array doesn't raise errors:

```
In [1]: foo = np.arange(3)

In [2]: foo
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [3]: foo[:64]
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: ah, I did not know this

Answer (score 3):

For the 1D case, it's not too bad:

```
a[:len(b)] = b[:len(a)]
```

For n-dimensional `a` and `b`, things get messier, although still reasonable for a helper function:

```
def mismatched_copyto(from, to):
    overlap_slices = tuple(slice(None, min(a, b)) for a, b in zip(from.shape, to.shape))
    to[overlap_slices] = from[overlap_slices]
```

If you want to define some sort of broadcasting for mismatched `ndim`s, it gets even messier. I don't think I'd bother.

Comment: Thanks, this actually is for an arbitrily multidimensional situation, though I thought I would post the base case in my question. I ended up with

`imageData = numpy.zeros((width*height, 3))` \n
        `for n in range(data):` \n
              `imageData[n][:len(data[n])] = data[n][:3]`, where `data` is the pixel data of an image of arbitrary size, and an aribtary number of channels, and `imageData` is a conversion to a three-channel RGB image, even if the initial number of channels was less than 3.